# Can I save my remembered password and cookies to a file?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, passwords

We all know that Firefox remember all your passwords and cookies, so you don't have to re-type them every time you access your mail, stack exchange or any other site that requires password

but when you format your device Firefox forget all this credentials, my questions are:

- How can I save my all remembered passwords and cookies from Firefox to a file ?
- How can I import the Information from this file to Firefox after format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All data in Firefox is stored in its [Profile](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data). You can find where the profile is located by going to your options menu (right of the search bar), click on the question mark, and view Troubleshooting Information. There, in Application Basics, you can view your profile folder.

If you are also looking for that for Google Chrome, just look up Chrome Profile locations, google will help you there.